# Requiring javascript with Clojurescript :bundle

Tags: clojurescript, react-datepicker

Using `ClojureScript :bundle`

- I can require other javascript libraries but `react-datepicker` is causing the followinf error:

  *react-dom.development.js:23965 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.*

This is how I requires the library

```
(:require ["react-datepicker" :as DatePicker])
```

Than I attempt to use it

```
($ DatePicker {...})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `react-datepicker` has a `default` export.

Try `($ DatePicker/default ...)` or with the upcoming CLJS release it would be `(:require ["react-datepicker$default" :as DatePicker])` but that is not released as of today and would require cloning `master`.